# jQuery Split content based on height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lot of data on page and I want to make it book style, instead of splitting the content based tags (div element), I want to split them based on height. Can anybody please teach me, how to split content in jquery based on heights?

I want vertical split instead of horizontal split in columns more like pagination but a actual split like google docs when we paste lot of content it automatically split into pages.

Comment: depends on the HTML.  Can we see some code?

Comment: Here is link http://jsbin.com/omeseg

Comment: How did you solved that if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

Shishant: The following plugin will have some solution for your problem. please check
http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Download the plugin and check the sample9.html demo. You might looking for the same I guess.

Answer (score -2):

You should look into using [CSS3 Columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). It should do this very nicely for you. Of course, the only issue is that it has [terrible support in IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=column).

Answer (score -2):

Take look at [CSS multicolumn layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm). Works on IE too.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am looking for, I am looking for content split like when we paste a lot of data in google docs it automatically split content to pages.

Comment: Well, in that case, use a `onpaste` handler and in that, apply a pagination plugin to the content that will create pages for you. You can style the pages to get the look and feel of google docs. Here's few: [SweetPages](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-a-jquery-pagination-solution/) and http://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-modern-jquery-pagination-for-content/

Comment: I have checked both, they both split content based on tags, lets say I have two divs one 1000px another 100px = total 1100px I want to split them into 500px div height