# Wrap text around a stationary divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to create an html element that doesn't move even if the content on the webpage changes it stays in the same position and the rest of the content wraps around it?

I want to create a long line that stretches across a dynamic webpage. When someone adds more content to the webpage, that line should stay intact and not move like a brick wall and the rest of the content maneuvers around it or jumps over it.

Visual example:

```
content content content content content contentcontent content
content content content content content contentcontent content co
--------------------------------------------------------------------(long line)
ntent content contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent content
content contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent contentcontent
```

Notice how on the 2nd line the text wraps over the long line to continue after the line.

Hope it makes sense,

Found this question, this is more or less exactly what I want [jQuery Split content based on height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032639/jquery-split-content-based-on-height)

The questioned wasn't answered though.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line if I may ask?

Comment: That example didnt come out right. I want a line that splits breaks the webpage in half on a fixed position where that line is. The content that will be split is all text so, I want it to flow on till after that line if it becomes too much in the top half of the page.

Comment: what would cause the text to change?

Comment: Have you looked at "float"?

Comment: The purpose is to visually show the user how many pages his content is going to fill up. Lets say I have enough content to fill 5 pages with text, there will be enough lines to split the content 5 times on that page. Kinda like ms word, the way it jumps to a new page after a page is filled up.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals how do you make it not move?

Comment: float doesnt work, the content doesnt wrap around the top of the line if I use float.

Comment: @misterdev you could move the float to the correct position in text by Javascript. Considering your goal, I'm going to suggest that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.fencepost {float: left; width: 0.1px; height: 100px;}
.gate {float: left; clear: left; width: 99.9%; height: 30px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/P6Z3p/

Comment: that's a clever little hack :)

Comment: Clever.  This creates a very narrow vertical element of height 100px on the left, of which a wide-bar of spacing bar is placed below, and then the text just fits around these two divs.

Comment: Here's a modification that adds page breaks automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/KbXzS/

Comment: Thats it! you took the problem and practically ripped its head off!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with CSS. You'd probably have a set character limit per 'page' and when you detect on a page that the character limit is over using javascript, you would force the user's focus onto a new 'page'.

The styling of the line is then irrelevant - its just a normal HTML element width 100% or something, the important bit is forcing the split on the user

Comment: I tried that route a hile ago but it wasnt accurate if the user added an image. I found this, this is more or less exactly what I want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032639/jquery-split-content-based-on-height

Comment: but that's vertical columns, not paging?

Comment: If I add a border at the bottom of each vertical column I achieve the same result. :)