# Wrap text around both sides of div

Tags: html, css, text

Here is what I try to achieve:

With the following `HTML`:

```
<div id="my1"> 
<p> some text </p>  
<div id="wrap">Awesome content</div>  
</div>
```

Having this:

```
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
text text text text text div id="wrap" text text text text text  
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

Floating `div`s didn't help me reaching this result so far... (considering height and width for both my1 and wrap are known)?

[image]

A fiddle where the text starts from the right side of the wrapped div, when I wish it starts from the left of "my1" div, breaks around "wrap" div.
http://jsfiddle.net/matmat/dxV4X/

Comment: Create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please reword and better describe what you want to achieve. You could also setup a fiddle to help us see your code better. thank you

Comment: Here's a fiddle that is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/matmat/dxV4X/ I wish that the text starts left, and wraps around the grey box

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you want something like float:center ? Well, the problem is that this property doesn't exist.

**Here are 2 alternatives:**

### 1) Fake it with pseudo elements - **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5w5A4/1/)** - See this [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/)

[image]

Set up markup like so:

```
<div>
    <div id="wrap">Awesome content</div>
    <div id="l">
        <p>left text here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="r">
        <p>right text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### With CSS

```
#wrap {
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
}
#l {
    float: left;
}
#r {
    float: right;
}
#l, #r {
    width: 49%;
}
#l:before, #r:before {
    content:"";
    width: 125px;
    height: 250px;
}
#l:before {
    float: right;
}
#r:before {
    float: left;
}
```

### Alternative #2 (IE 10+ only): [CSS Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/) - **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/BXnA7/3/)**

[image]

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="exclusion">Awesome content which floats in the center</div>
    <div class="dummy_text">all the text here</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    font-size: small;
    background: aqua;
    position: relative;
}
.exclusion {
    background-color: lime;
    -ms-wrap-flow: both;
    -ms-wrap-margin: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: auto;
}
```

For more info about CSS exclusion browser support and further resources see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895616/703717).

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="my1">
    <p>some text some text
       <span id="wrap">wrapped text</span>
       some text some text</p>
</div>
```

Should work if I am reading the question correctly? A `<div`> is a block level element which is breaking, a `<span>` is inline like what you want.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YbuuH/2/

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. The wrapped div can contain various hmtl content.

Answer (score -1):

Use css as below:

> ## wrap { word-wrap:break-word; }

This css should work to wrap the text in a line and to continue on next.