# html css float not wraping around top of image,

Tags: html, css

I float an image to the right of a paragraph with `margin-top: 70px`.

The text floats under the image, but it does not float over the image.

how do I get the text to flow over the top of the image as shown by the red rectangle in the provided image. I added the red rectangle to the screen shot, it is not native to the html or css.

```css
.floatright {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin-top: 70px; 
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="floatright" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Regular_polygon_3_annotated.svg/1200px-Regular_polygon_3_annotated.svg.png" alt="foo"/>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</p>
```

[image: the floated image]

Comment: this is how float works

Comment: Please include an [mcve]. Makes it far easier for people to help you.

Comment: you may get some idea here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770925/floating-an-image-to-the-bottom-right-with-text-wrapping-around

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve it with `shape-outside`

[image]

```css
div {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    shape-outside: border-box;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
p{
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="floatright" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*kOuvkQUrByiaqZYTZFJz4g.png" alt="foo"/>
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu quo duis aperiam, id has ferri placerat suavitate. Vis oratio bonorum ei, discere delicata pro no. Erant maiestatis et cum. Est iusto veritus et, liber tollit sensibus his eu. Eam cu errem persius.

Sumo accusata eam id. Te expetenda iudicabit delicatissimi ius. Nec ut laoreet argumentum, sed ad erat libris. Vim ullum omnium te. Mel mazim noster delicatissimi no, conceptam philosophia vim ea, vix esse soleat mucius in. Ne quod explicari pri, eam diceret nonumes accumsan id.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu quo duis aperiam, id has ferri placerat suavitate. Vis oratio bonorum ei, discere delicata pro no. Erant maiestatis et cum. Est iusto veritus et, liber tollit sensibus his eu. Eam cu errem persius.

Sumo accusata eam id. Te expetenda iudicabit delicatissimi ius. Nec ut laoreet argumentum, sed ad erat libris. Vim ullum omnium te. Mel mazim noster delicatissimi no, conceptam philosophia vim ea, vix esse soleat mucius in. Ne quod explicari pri, eam diceret nonumes accumsan id.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu quo duis aperiam, id has ferri placerat suavitate. Vis oratio bonorum ei, discere delicata pro no. Erant maiestatis et cum. Est iusto veritus et, liber tollit sensibus his eu. Eam cu errem persius.

Sumo accusata eam id. Te expetenda iudicabit delicatissimi ius. Nec ut laoreet argumentum, sed ad erat libris. Vim ullum omnium te. Mel mazim noster delicatissimi no, conceptam philosophia vim ea, vix esse soleat mucius in. Ne quod explicari pri, eam diceret nonumes accumsan id.


 </p>
```

Jus for reference `css shape` lack support for `IE` and `Edge`

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

Comment: when you run the code snippet  - the text does not float over the picture. It floats on the bottom of the picture, not the top

Comment: @capser What browser are you using?

Comment: @capser I have added image of how it looks to me and it seems as per your question

Comment: Works for me on chrome

Comment: explorer 9 we do not have chrome at the office.

Comment: it will not support `IE` and `Edge`, check updated answer

Comment: @capser You should mention in the question that you want specifically an IE9 answer. That browser is obsolete and practically dead, so any usual modern approaches won't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use, `shape outside` on the image.

If you enable my `border-radius` here, it will work with the ellipse as well.

Also - Note that I put your Image outside/Next to the paragraph

```css
.yourImage {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    float: right;
    shape-outside: content-box;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: MediumPurple;
    background-clip: content-box;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img class="yourImage" src="whatever">

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
  of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
  in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

look the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Float basic</title>
<style> 
.body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
 .floatright { float: right;
               border: 1px solid black; 
               margin-top: 10px ; 
               height: 150px;
               width: auto;
                } 
}

#txt1{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}


</style> 

</head>

<body>
<img class="floatright" src="img.png" alt="Java"/>
<p id="txt1">ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>


<p id="txt1">ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p id="txt1">ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CtOv.png)

Comment: While code is useful for showing the solution, it's recommended that you give an explanation as to what your code does and how it solves the problem. This would not only give the OP an idea of what is going on in your code, but also for those future Googlers too.

Comment: @capser Posts are upvoted and downvoted based on their quality and not on how long the author has been a contributor. Did this answer help solve your problem in any way? If not, why shouldn't it be downvoted?